# TestFailure (Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "0" (ignoring offstage widgets)>

Tags: flutter

i created a simple app to capture id and save to gallery, but when i run my app it give me this error

Exception has occurred.
TestFailure (Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "0" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
Which: means none were found but one was expected
)

i checked all the possible reason but i cant find where the problem is, really would appreciate if you can give me some advice with this, TIA

here is may code, TIA

```
`import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_ml_vision/firebase_ml_vision.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'ID Capture with OCR',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image= File('');
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  String _text = '';

  Future getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
    readText();
  }

  Future readText() async {
    FirebaseVisionImage visionImage = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(_image);
    TextRecognizer textRecognizer = FirebaseVision.instance.textRecognizer();
    VisionText visionText = await textRecognizer.processImage(visionImage);

    setState(() {
      _text = visionText.text!;
    });
  }

  Future<void> saveImage() async {
    if (_image != null && _text != null) {
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final name = 'ID-${DateTime.now().toString()}.jpg';
      final path = '${directory.path}/$name';
      await _image.copy(path);

      setState(() {
        _image = Null as File;
        _text = '';
      });

      final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(path);
      print('File saved to gallery: $result');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final width = size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('ID Capture with OCR'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: width - 32,
              height: width - 32,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
              ),
              child: _image == null
                  ? const Center(
                      child: Text('No image selected.'),
                    )
                  : Image.file(_image),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text(_text),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: getImage,
                  child: const Text('Take Picture'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 16),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: saveImage,
                  child: const Text('Save Image'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
`
```